# How Spark Structured Streaming maps executor cores Kafka topic partition. Does Dynamic allocation changes the mapping at runtime. if yes how?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

Can someone explain how Spark Structured Streaming maps each spark executor core Kafka topic partition.
Does enabling Dynamic allocation changes the mapping at runtime. if yes how?

If possible can you please point me to the spark code in github repo where Spark updates this executor core to topic partition mapping?

Comment: There is no specific Spark code. This is handled internally in Kafka Consumer Group logic. Spark dynamic allocation would cause a group rebalance

Comment: But how would spark cause rebalance in the first place?

Comment: Dynamic allocation would cause additional tasks (Kafka consumers) to be created for the same app (consumer group)